# Count how many times a C function is executed

Tags: c, function

There is this C function which is executed until area1/area2 are less than a defined constant. What I want to do is to find and return how many times this function is executed. Is there a way to return both the rate area1/area2 and the counter value?

```
double area(double x, double y) {
  x=......
  y=......
  if( (area1/area2) > CONSTANT ) {
    area1 = area(x,y);
    area2 = area(x,y);
  }
  return area1/area2;

}
```

Comment: The code you have doesn't work. You use `area1` and `area2` before they are defined or initialized. As such, it's unclear how the recursion should work.

Comment: Use a static variable.

Comment: @codah: static wont work since you'll not be able to access it outside this function, OP wants to read this value when this function exits.

Comment: @brokenfoot True missed that.

Answer (score 2):

Add the counter as an extra parameter:

```
double area(double x, double y, int *count) 
{
    (*count)++;
    ....
    return area1/area2;
}
```

Declare and initialise the `count` variable elsewhere, and pass its address every time you call the function.

```
int count = 0;
....
double a = area(x, y, &count);
```

Comment: As I am newbie in C, could you please explain how should I declare and initialise count? Moreover, when calling area method in

    area1 = area(x,y);
    area2 = area(x,y);

what should I use in the place of int *count? I mean, 
area1=area(x,y, ????);?

Comment: I added example calls to the answer

Comment: I get this error: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int **'

Comment: That's because your code is different from mine. You need to learn this stuff from your textbook. Can we please concentrate on the question you asked.

Answer (score 1):

Create a global variable whose value can be modified from everywhere inside the program. Just type something like "int counter = 0" and increase its value into the function.

Here is some code:

int counter = 0;

void function(){

counter++;

//some code here
}

main(){

function()

}